# Mixed drink with tonic water already added?

Tags: alcohol, alcohol-content

Anyone know of any pre-made mixed drinks with tonic water already included that can be purchased from a liquor store?

Comment: Where in the world ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

Fentimans's Bloom Gin & Tonic

http://www.fentimans.com/drinks/pre-mixed-alcoholic-drinks

There is a list here (UK oriented)

https://www.goodhousekeeping.co.uk/institute/food-reviews/pre-mixed-gin-and-tonic